# Cannot Redeclare class Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I am newbie to doctrine. I have existing doctrine 2.0 and zend framework 1.2 project ,I deleted the old vendor directory and use

**1. php composer.phar install**

**2. php composer.phar update**

to create a  new vendor folder. But it has problem with persistence file of doctrine. The error goes as follows  **Cannot redeclare class Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\FileDriver.** I cannot figure out why I am getting this problem.
My folder structure are
I create model classes manually and xml to map them 
then using doctrine commands

*php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create*

*php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities /tmp*

*php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-proxies application/models-proxy*

Comment: The error just sais that Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\FileDriver is declared twice so the related file exists twice I guess. Something went wrong when you where deleting/installing/updating or whatever.

Comment: ya i recopied the file n it worked thanks